# How to know the position of the scrollbar in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scrollbar

I want to get the actual position (scrollY) of the scrollbar something like below.
http://plnkr.co/edit/45gKhAIt0DrozS7f0Bz2?p=preview
I need to get this type of scrollY result for my div rather than the entire window. How can I do that in angularjs?

```
angular.element($window).bind('scroll',function(){
    console.log(' --- You scrolled - do $digest() ---')
    $scope.scrollY = $window.scrollY;
    $scope.$digest();
})
```

Comment: I think if you're looking for the scroll position on a div you might have to rely on offsetTop to compute it, I'm not an HTML or Angular expert though so there might be a better option...   Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div")).forEach(function(item,idx,array){console.log(item.offsetTop)}) keep in mind this is non-standard https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop I've seen some snippets out there for finding the actual position based on all the parents offsets but can't recall the reasoning honestly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is not angular, just standard JavaScript: `.scrollTop`

```
yourDiv.scrollTop
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/Tf7bq/2/ (The value is logged in the console.)

**UPDATE**

Changed listener to listen for scroll on the div.  Angular doesn't have a nice way to listen for scroll (like it does for certain other events), so a standard JavaScript event listener is used.  You can wrap this in a directive to make it more angular.

New example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/Tf7bq/4/

```
yourDiv.addEventListener('scroll',function(){

    console.log(this.scrollTop);

});
```

Comment: On-scrolling I need to get the updated value. Is there anyway?

Comment: You want to listen for the scroll event in that div.  Each event you can use `.scrolltop` to get the new/current value.  I will update my answer and example to include this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! for info we also have onscroll event directly.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne in angular you can bind to the scroll event since it has ".bind" method part of its jqlite subset of jQuery... it also has ".on" method as well

Comment: @DavidChase That is true, +1 to you :D  but I was think more of the `ng-click`, `ng-mouseover`, `ng-change`... and so on that they have that can easily be added to the element directly in the template.

Comment: thats why like you said you make this scroll functionality into a directive so its more angular :)